# Nav-Bar difficulty: should I be editing static blocks, html, css or..?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, navigation

I am currently trying to customise an existing theme (accessshop). I have managed to change images & text throughout most of the website. But I am struggling to make my nav-bar display my pages.

I have been using the inspector tool to locate css style / id's and editing the file / text either inside the static blocks or css files in the root.

My theme only currently shows a 'Home' Button. I have several other stock pages that were preloaded with Magento, none of these are showing. I have also tried creating a new page and this is bringing no luck either.

Should I be editing HTML code to add new navbar items / subitems? I presumes I would be able to do this through the Magento CMS.

Am I missing something? - thriffft.com

Some images are attached..

[image: Static Blocks]

[image: Inspector Tool focused on 'Home' within nav-bar]

Thanks in advanced

Comment: You want a new menu in menu bar right

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, i'm learning this as I go. But where will I find the 'menu bar right'. It's not a static block, should I be searching my CSS for this?

Comment: under menu bar want to add product page or custom page

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? In the stock theme, any new pages created would be automatically added to the nav-bar. Is this an error within the theme?

Comment: if you want cms page /static block in menu right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add category then goto

```
Catalog-> Manage category-> then left side click root catalog-> Add subcategory

Name : Category Name 
is Active : yes
Include Navigation : yes
then another tab 
display setting 
is anchor : yes
```

if you want to custom page in menu

You create static block

On that block you call that file like

```
{{block type="core/templae" template="template_Path_Here"}}
```

then create New menu

```
Name : Category Name 
is Active : yes
Include Navigation : yes
then another tab 
display setting 
Display mode : Select static block only
cms block : select your static block
```